# Entity Framework не отображает свойства

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть два класса `Author` и `Book`

```
 public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public bool InStock { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Discont { get; set; }

        public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }


    }
    public class Author
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books{ get; set; }


    }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
```

Если я в коде напишу

```
   var auth = db.Authors.ToList();
```

То система не показывает мне книги автора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 4):

```
var auth = db.Authors.Include(a => a.Books).ToList();
```